How to make a grid that is like a flex row wrap but if the height differes it wont stretch the elements
I am making a grid which will contain some cards. This is for a home automation dashboard so I will have some cards with less content and some with more.
What I want to accoplish is to have a grid that is like a flex row wrap, but if one grid item has less content it wont get "streched" to fit the other elemetnts on the same row. I dont want it to be like this:

In this image, you can see that the left element is stretched.
This is my css:
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(33%, 1fr));
    gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #121314;
    padding: 20px;
}

.card-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.horizontal-line {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

Here is my frontend:
function FluidGrid({ devices }: Readonly<{ devices: IDevice[][] }>) {
    return (
        <div className="grid-container">
            {devices.map(deviceArray => (
                <div className="grid-item">
                    {deviceArray.map(device => (
                        <DeviceControl key={device.id} device={device} />
                    ))}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

Thanks in advance!
Best regards Max
